# socket.io, занизить скорость upload

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Коллеги, использую socket.io. Закачиваю файлы на сервер. Как занизить скорость upload? Необходимо помедленнее бы сделать этот процесс, для отладки работы при длительных операциях. Сейчас у меня файл 45мег upload за 1 секунду, т.к. всё крутится локально. Хотел бы растянуть это время на 1-2 минуты.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/network-conditions почему бы не сделать это на уровне браузера?

Comment: GONG, с обычными загрузками проходит, это супер, спасибо, буду знать, а вот с сокетами - не проходит, скорость фактическая как и была.